# Self clearing an interval inside jquery.each()

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I need to position/resize an image with [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) just after it has loaded. To keep the aspect ratio intact I have to know the image's width/height. I can use the `.load` event, but this fires way too late, making the repositioning visible. Instead I use the following technique.

```
 var interval = setInterval(function(){
     if ($('img').height()) { //This means we have got height.
          //Code that uses $('img').height().
          clearInterval(interval);
     }
 },10);
```

This makes sure that the code is executed just when I have width/height information for the image, and before it's fully loaded.

Now, however, I need to do this for a bunch of images (specifically in a jQuery plugin) and the problem seems to be that the first `clearInterval` invocation clears all the intervals, leaving all but the first `img` untouched.

I have tried saving the interval id in the `$(this)` jQuery object both as a property (`$(this).interval = setInterval( ...` and as data `$(this).data("interval", setInterval( ...`.

I also tried saving the id in a variable first as above and then assigning it to `$(this).data("interval",interval)` just after the closing parenthesis of the `setInterval` call.

What is the correct way to do this so that every interval clears itself and only itself?

Full listing of my code follows

```
(function($){
   $.fn.extend({
       centerInParent: function(options) {
           var defaults = {
               mode: "fill", //Fill or fit (not implemented)
               padding: 100
           }
           var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
           return this.each(function() {
               var o = options;
               $t = $(this)
               $p = $t.parent();
               var interval = setInterval(function(){
                   $t.css({position:"absolute", width:"", height:""})
                   if ($t.height()){
                       parentRatio = $p.innerWidth()/$p.innerHeight();
                       thisRatio = $t.innerWidth()/$t.innerHeight();
                       if (thisRatio > parentRatio) var newWidth = $p.innerWidth() - o.padding; else var newWidth = ($p.innerHeight() - o.padding)*thisRatio;
                       var newHeight = newWidth/thisRatio
                       $t.css({
                           width: newWidth,
                           height:newHeight,
                           marginTop: ($p.innerHeight() - newHeight)/2,
                           marginLeft: ($p.innerWidth() - newWidth)/2
                       })
                       clearInterval($t.data("interval"));
                   }
               }, 10)
               $t.data("interval",interval)
           });
       }
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: you should figure out why `onload` fires too late, not mess around with polling.

Comment: Have you considered hiding all the images, resizing them onload and then showing them, so you don't get the visual resizing?

Comment: the images are too big (1000+ pixels) so onload correctly fires too late (waits until the images have fully loaded), while the height comes around after 10-20ms (I suppose just after the browser reads the image headers). Hiding until load is also not an option as the image may take one or two seconds to load fully. Finally I use progressive encoding for images so the images are shown well before all the data has downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- shouldn't `$t` and `$p` not be global variables? i.e. be declared as

  ```
  var $t = $(this),
      $p = t.parent();
  ```
- the method to load the image and wait for 10 msec to compute their size is dangerous in my opinion: it could yield to different results in different browsers
- better preload the images and compute their size before displaying them :

  ```
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://your-image-url';
  $(img).load(function(){
      // here, deal with img.width and img.height
      // and then display
  });
  ```

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head with the scope suggestion.  I didn't spot that till you pointed it out :)

Comment: I think that the scope will solve the problem, yes. I'll check and then accept your answer if this solves it. Preloading is not an option as the images show up upon first page loading and I want them to immediately appear resized to fit the window. Until css contain is universally supported this ugly hack is still the only solution. (Unless there is some onsizecalculated event that I don't know)

Comment: Regarding danger, my experience has shown that it works acceptably cross-browser. As it's an interval and not a timeout, it doesn't wait just 10ms, it waits until a non-zero value has been produced. In general on dom ready, Firefox has computed the sizes while Chrome hasn't, so that isn't the right event to use either.

Comment: Indeed I misread interval as timeout. Well that's the trick I could think of when I could not use CSS contain.